# 82 additional commits have been omitted to prevent performance issues. gitLab

Tags: git, merge, gitlab, merge-request

I've release merge request on gitlab which contains almost 200 commits, but I can't load whole list cuz the gitLab shows me something like this below commit list:
`82 additional commits have been omitted to prevent performance issues.`

How can I see my whole list of commits for this merge request? Or what it actually means? If I merge this merge request all of change will be added to target branch?

---

How should I merge this merge request in correct way?

Answer (score 1):

You can search for the commit history of the branch that you are trying to merge.
Click the source branch in your merge request -> go to commits

You will be able to see all of the commits made to that branch.
All of the changes will be merged to the target branch.

**Note**: the real problem comes when you have deleted that branch and you need to view those 82 additional commits afterwards.